# Not able to make TypeScript work in VS 2013 Express

Tags: visual-studio, typescript

I am trying to make TypeScript work in Visual Studio 2013 Express for Web.

I downloaded it directly from http://www.typescriptlang.org/ today.

There are no templates and it does not recognize any .ts file.

Any ideas?

**Answer:**

There was a bug, fortunately **it's fixed in VS 2013 Update 3 RC**

Download the update here: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=397827

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio 2013 Update 3 RC fixed this issue.

Download here: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=397827

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be problems:

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/874802/visual-studio-2013-express-update-2-no-typescript

http://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/2547

Hopefully the issue is fixed soon.